# Strange "There is already an object in the database." error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#PropList') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #PropList

DECLARE @Split CHAR(1), @propList NVARCHAR(MAX), @PropListXml XML
SET @Split = ','
SET @propList = 'NAME,DESCRIPTION'
-- SET @propList = ''

IF (@propList IS NOT NULL AND @propList != '')
  BEGIN
    SET @PropListXml = CONVERT(XML,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@propList, @Split, '</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

    SELECT SystemName = T.c.VALUE('.','nvarchar(36)')
    INTO #PropList
    FROM @PropListXml.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT SystemName
    INTO #PropList -- Stops here
    FROM tblProperty
  END

SELECT * FROM #PropList
```

Regardless of the value of `@propList`, this code always stops at the indicated line with this error:

> There is already an object named '#PropList' in the database.

My expectation was that only one of the two IF blocks is executed, therefore there should be only one attempt to create the table with the `SELECT... INTO` statement. Why is this failing?

Comment: Try explicitly creating `#PropList` before the `IF`, then do an `INSERT INTO #PropList SELECT ...`.

Comment: @ChrisPickford: That worked for me. I am just puzzled why it is not working like this

Comment: This error is generated during code parsing (and before execution) and code parsing does not execute control flow statements (as you would expect). Use @Chris Pickford answer to work around the problem.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828261/why-does-sql-server-thinks-a-temp-table-already-exists-when-it-doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment, you'll need to explicitly define your `#temp` table before the `IF` statement, then change your

```
SELECT ... INTO #temp
```

to be

```
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT ...
```

This is because when SQL Server validates the query it ignores any control flow statements. For more detail on this see the following SO question:

[T-Sql appears to be evaluating "If" statement even when the condition is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822843/t-sql-appears-to-be-evaluating-if-statement-even-when-the-condition-is-not-tru)