# SQL server Json with single array

Tags: json, sql-server

I am storing ids in comma separated string.

e.g

```
 1,2,3,4
```

How can I store this in JSON in the column and should be able to insert delete any particular value?

Thanks

Comment: You should at least post some information about the table structure, the desired JSON output and about what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have done google but din't find any example showing single value in json array, its using key value pairs

Comment: `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[1,2,3,4]') WITH ([value] INT '$')`; `SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG([value],',') + ']' FROM (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[1,2,3,4]') WITH ([value] INT '$') EXCEPT SELECT 3) _`. In short: don't do this if you can help it. Use properly normalized tables if updating is something you'll be doing frequently. JSON support is not there as a way to support improperly normalized tables. Even if your input is primarily JSON, it's trivial to convert tables back to JSON, so that's not really an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the following answer comes from here, so all credits go there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844117/2695832

Here's a solution that enables you to store your string values in a JSON array in a table column. However, the *should be able to insert delete any particular value* part of your question is not totally clear to me.

```
DECLARE @source  VARCHAR(20);
SET @source = '1,2,3,4';

DECLARE @values TABLE
(
    [Id]  VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @values
(
    [Id]
)
       SELECT 
           value
       FROM [STRING_SPLIT](@source, ',')
           WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';

INSERT INTO @values ([Id]) VALUES ('5')

DELETE FROM @values WHERE Id = 2

SELECT  
JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + Id + '"' 
FROM @values FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' ) ids  
FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

This produces the following JSON object:

```
{"ids":["1","3","4","5"]}
```

The code might need some tweaking to completely match your needs since you're probably not using a table variable and also maybe want to use a numeric data type for your id values.

Comment: should be able to insert, means I can append one more id

Comment: With the proposed solution you could insert whatever additional values you want into the table variable.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to delete any value

Comment: Depending on your delete criteria for example: `DELETE FROM @values WHERE Id = 2` before the XML-JSON-statement.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get

Comment: I added INSERT and DELETE statements. If this is still not sufficient you should really update your question to clarify what you're after.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. My last edit obviously broke the SQL code, some characters were cut off. Fixed the code.

Comment: 'JSON_QUERY' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: This is probably a matter of your SQL Server version and its compatibility level: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699201/how-to-check-are-there-json-functions-by-sql-query